# Winform doesnot show up when i tried to open from a backgroundworker_RunWorkerCompleted event?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

the detail of my action is i have a winform which contains only progress bar which i made to do some calculations and stored the final value in db.for this i used progress bar and backgroundworker thread.
i am doing all calculation in backgroundworker thread event doWork event.
When backgroundworker is finish it calls RunWorkerCompleted event, in which i am trying to open another winform.
The problem is that winform doesnt get visible.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(click)) { 
        if (click == "sales") { 
           Sales sales = new Sales(); 
           sales.MdiParent = mdiStockApp.mdi; 
           sales.Show(); 
           sales.Activate(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

this is the RunWorkerCompleted event in which i am trying to open another event. just now i tried with form.Activate() too but still no

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet showing what you have tried to open the other form?

Comment: sure 
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(click))
            {
                if (click == "sales")
                {
                    Sales sales = new Sales();
                    sales.MdiParent = mdiStockApp.mdi;
                    sales.Show();
                    sales.Activate();
                }
            }
        }

this is the RunWorkerCompleted event in which i am trying to open another event.
just now i tried with form.Activate() too but still no

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `if()` statements? Does it work with a form other than `Sales`?

Comment: no. its not working even without if code.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that BackgroundWorker OnWorkCompleted throws cross-thread exception ? Try UI handling in another thread, check this.IsInvokeRequired property and use this.Invoke(...)

Comment: when i call sales.Show() and try to debug it never goes to Sales form. any reasons???